# Removing an element from a ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to remove the String match "Meg" by using the ArrayList and for loop. So far I have written the code below and not sure why it's not working. I think the problem is with the below `while` loop

```
while((customerName.get(i)).equals("Meg"))
{
  customerName.remove(i);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Complete code is as below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class CustomerLister2
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<String> customerName = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    customerName.add("Chris");
    customerName.add("Lois");
    customerName.add("Meg");
    customerName.add("Peter");
    customerName.add("Stewie");
    customerName.add(3, "Meg");
    customerName.add(4, "Brian");

    int currentSize = customerName.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < currentSize - 1; i++)
    {

      while((customerName.get(i)).equals("Meg"))
      {
        customerName.remove(i);
      }
    }
    for(String newStr: customerName)
    {
      System.out.println(newStr);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using while loop within for loop? Only if statement( instead of while loop) should have worked

Comment: I just started learning java. Thanks for telling me that, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to the following

```
for(int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
{
  if((customerName.get(i)).equals("Meg"))
  {
    customerName.remove(i);
    i--;  //because a new element may be at i now
    currentSize = customerName.size(); //size has changed
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't have to use a for loop:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> customerName = new ArrayList<String>();
        customerName.add("Chris");
        customerName.add("Lois");
        customerName.add("Meg");
        customerName.add("Peter");
        customerName.add("Stewie");
        customerName.add(3, "Meg");
        customerName.add(4, "Brian");

        while (customerName.remove("Meg")) {}

        for (String s : customerName) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
System.out.println("Customer Name (including Meg)"+customerName);
for(int i=0; i<customerName.size(); i++)
{
  String s = customerName.get(i);
  if(s.equals("Meg"))
  {
     customerName.remove(i);
     i--;
  }
}
System.out.println("Customer Name (excluding Meg)"+customerName);
```

Comment: This will not work if there are consecutive elements having value "Meg".

Comment: @uba: Thanks for looking at that case. I have updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use iterator `customerName.iterator()` (iterator() is non-static method)
Iterator takes care of list's count modification. We might forget to take care of list's count modification when we use `for` loop.

```
Iterator<String> itr= customerName.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
{
    if(itr.next().equals("Meg")){
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Drawback also there in iterator. It doesn't work if two threads are concurrently accessing the same list object. Ex. One thread is reading and another thread is removing element from the list then it throws `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException.` Better to use `Vector` in concurrent scenario.

If you still want to use same `for` loop then add following line of code.

```
int currentSize = customerName.size();

for(int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
{

  while((customerName.get(i)).equals("Meg"))
  {
    customerName.remove(i);
    currentSize = customerName.size(); //add this line to avoid run-time exception.
  }
}
```